# Expected file to define module, but it is defined... why does ruby disagree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The first line of text is the LoadError
the second line of text in the image is the folder where the file, shared.rb resides in my rails project.
And the sytax colored stuff is the top part of shared.rb

[image]

as you can see, shared.rb defines NamedScope::Shared, so why is RoR saying that it isn't?

using rails 2.3.8

UPDATE:

tried this:

```
module NamedScope
    module Shared
```

in the same file, `shared.rb` in `{AppRoot}/lib/named_scope/`
which also didn't work (same error)

UPDATE 2: This error was caused my a model class not having a Constant defined.

I just had

```
CONSTANT_NAME
```

instead of

```
CONSTANT_NAME = value
```

this is upsetting, as I feel lied to o.o

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the NamedScope module before? You might need to do:

```
module NamedScope
  module Shared
    # do your thing here
  end
end
```

Comment: just tried this: didn't work. =(

updtating question to include example.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see more of the code to follow.

I've had that issue when the code uses a Class that is defined somewhere else and the magic name resolution is not strong enough. Like if I have a XyzLoan class that extends the Loan class but I did not require it or use it before. It shouldn't fail but it does.

If that is the case you can do a binary search for the problem by removing halves of the code and try again until you find what is causing it.

Comment: well, the file that is having issues hasn't been changed in months. So... I'm really confused.But, basically, all I'm doing is adding a named scope to all my models by doing this:

`  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do `

Comment: found the problem... unrelated to the error though. The error I was given was a lie. o.o

Comment: Sorry! Rails has a weird way to give errors sometimes. Doing the binary search sometimes has helped me find what the heck is going on or at least where.